# Can an NSAutoreleasePool be drained twice or multiple times?

Tags: cocoa, nsautoreleasepool

In the book I'm reading, it talks about forcing an `NSAutoreleasePool` to drain. Does this mean creating a local `NSAutoreleasePool` and then draining it, instead of draining the one that already exists?  That is, can I not drain an `NSAutoreleasePool` twice or multiple times?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What else did you find about this when you read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot drain an autorelease pool more than once.

> does it mean creating a local NSAutoreleasePool and then drain it

Yes.  Either make a new pool and drain it, or (even better) use `@autoreleasepool`.

> we cannot drain a NSAutoreleasePool twice or multiple time?

Correct.  [The documentation for `drain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000051-SW1) states:

> In a reference-counted environment, this method behaves the same as release. Since an autorelease pool cannot be retained (see [retain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAutoreleasePool/retain)), this therefore causes the receiver to be deallocated.

Since an autorelease pool gets deallocated after the first call to `drain`, it is never valid to call **any** method on it afterwards, `drain` included.